# Adding {meta:tags} to Masonry on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr, jquery-masonry

This might sound a bit odd.

I'm trying to make my first tumblr theme and also trying to make it highly customisable.

ie using meta tags instead of hard coded values

```
<meta name="color:Title" content="#000000"/>

.title {
color:{color:Title};
}
```

etc

One of the things i'm trying to customise is ***gutter width*** - this is currently held in a Masonry variable

```
$tumblelog.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $tumblelog.masonry({
            columnWidth: 500,       // DEFINES POST WIDTH IN PX
            gutterWidth: 10,        // DEFINES GUTTER WITDH IN PX
            isFitWidth: true        // CENTERS COLUMNS ON PAGE
        });
    });
```

although i don't really understand how i can add an html meta tag to that JS value.
(i imagine i can't.)

but is there a way i can call that value from outside the script or something?
how do i make that customisable?

thanks :)

---

F I X E D : although StackOverflow doesn't let me answer my own question yet :)

---

ah that was easier than I thought

create Meta tag ie

```
<meta name="text:Gutter" content="20"/>
```

then add meta discriptor to JS

```
   gutterWidth: {text:Gutter},     // DEFINES GUTTER WITDH IN PX
```

turns out it just works but the tumblr editor bugs out at first

just have to SAVE+CLOSE and it auto updates :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah that was easier than I thought

create Meta tag
ie

```
<meta name="text:Gutter" content="20"/>
```

then add meta discriptor to JS

```
gutterWidth: {text:Gutter},     // DEFINES GUTTER WITDH IN PX
```

turns out it just works but the tumblr *editor* bugs out at first - just have to SAVE+CLOSE and it auto updates :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<meta name="masonry:gutterWidth" content="10"/>

var gutterWidth = {masonry:gutterWidth};

$tumblelog.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $tumblelog.masonry({
        columnWidth: 500,           // DEFINES POST WIDTH IN PX
        gutterWidth: gutterWidth,   // DEFINES GUTTER WITDH IN PX
        isFitWidth: true            // CENTERS COLUMNS ON PAGE
    });
});
```